# generating a multidimensional numpy array such that a[x,y] = [x,y] (calculating essential matrix from dense optical flow)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, opticalflow

I need to take the output `flow` (shaped (cols,rows,2)) of a dense optical flow calculated through this:

`flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(im0, im1, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)`

and generate 2 one-dimensional lists of points `old_pts` and `new_pts` such that:

- `old_pts` is a list of pixel coordinates `[[y,x],...]`
- `new_pts` is a list of corrected pixel coordinates: `[[y+flow[y,x][1],x+flow[y,x][0]],...]`

it is crucial that the 2 lists are ordered in the same way so that old_pts[i] is referring to same pixel as new_pts[i]
i.e. old_pts[1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga5d10ebbd59fe09c5f650289ec0ece5af) = [0,1] => new_pts[1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga5d10ebbd59fe09c5f650289ec0ece5af) = [0+flow[0,1](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga5d10ebbd59fe09c5f650289ec0ece5af),1+flow[0,1][0]]

[opencv docs reference](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga5d10ebbd59fe09c5f650289ec0ece5af)

to feed them into this:
`E,_ = cv2.findEssentialMat(old_pts,new_pts,ch.K)`

i've got the following working solution (but it's terribly slow [~15" on a 4k image]):

```
    old_pts = []
    new_pts = []
    for y in range(cols):
        for x in range(rows):
            old_pts.append([y,x])
            new_pts.append([y+flow[y,x][1],x+flow[y,x][0]])
    
    old_pts = np.array(old_pts)
    new_pts = np.array(new_pts)
```

is there a better (numpythonic) way to generate the two point lists?

what i think it should be done is:

- generating and filling an image-shaped array "a" such that a[x,y] = [x,y]
- flipping flow axis 2
- adding a to the flipped flow
- reshape and transpose a and the result to generate the two points lists

Example of what i need:

```
this is `flow` (in real life is 3000x4000):  
| y,x |         0        |       1        |        2       |
|-----|------------------|----------------|----------------|
|   0 | [[[-0.81,-0.55], | [0.73,0.83],   | [-0.3,-0.86]], |
|   1 | [[-0.33,-0.71],  | [0.86,-0.27],  | [0.11,-0.03]], |
|   2 | [[0.46,-0.51],   | [-0.35,-0.88], | [0.4,-0.7]]]   |

this is what i need:  
| old_pts |        new_pts      |
|---------|---------------------|
| [[0,0], | [[0+-0.55,0+-0.81], |
| [1,0],  | [1+-0.71,0+-0.33],  |
| [2,0],  | [2+-0.51,0+0.46],   |
| [0,1],  | [0+0.83,1+0.73],    |
| [1,1],  | [1+-0.27,1+0.86],   |
| [2,1],  | [2+-0.88,1+-0.35],  |
| [0,2],  | [0+-0.86,2+-0.3],   |
| [1,2],  | [1+-0.03,2+0.11],   |
| [2,2]]  | [2+-0.7,2+0.4]]     |
```

Comment: kind of difficult to me to understand, why dont you add the flow as new axes to your image converted to array and then get the two list you need from the array itself ?

Comment: added an example. (sry for using "code tag" it won't let me add the tables for some reasons)

Comment: are you sure about your flow output ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131822/what-is-output-from-opencvs-dense-optical-flow-farneback-function-how-can-th

Comment: ok got it wasnt able to read your table

Comment: trying to understand ho cv2calcOpticalFlowFarneback works unfortunately I am on no more qustion ban on stackoverflow, how do you cope withs [[y+flow[y,x][1],x+flow[y,x][0]],...] giving that we are talking int pixel coordinates and flow vector returns  floating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a much faster solution:

```
    xes = np.tile(np.arange(im0.shape[1]),(im0.shape[0],1))
    yes = np.tile(np.arange(im0.shape[0])[:,None],(1,im0.shape[1]))

    nxes = xes + flow[:,:,0]
    nyes = yes + flow[:,:,1]

    xy  = np.stack((yes,xes),axis = 2)
    nxy = np.stack((nyes,nxes),axis = 2)

    old_pts = np.reshape(xy,(-1, xy.shape[-1]))
    new_pts = np.reshape(nxy,(-1, nxy.shape[-1]))
```

Comment: So you are basically summing array instead of iterating on array elements and doing the sum for each element. How faster is that for your 4K image ?

Comment: haven't measured it properly, but definitely less than 1" now (so at least 15x faster)